# Get all match from regexp in string as the result of search (/<regexp>)

Tags: regex, vim

So I'm looking for a way to get all parameters of a function (in Python) defined like this

`def a_function(param1, param2="foo", somethingelse):`

I made a regexp (sorry for your eyes, i'm not that good at regexping) which match all the parameters if I use the research in vim (/regexp)

```
\(def[[:blank:]]\+[_[:alnum:]]\+[[:blank:]]*(.*\)\@<=\([_[:alnum:]]\+[[:blank:]]*=\@=\|[_[:alnum:]]\+[[:blank:]]*,\@=\|\(,[[:blank:]]*\)\@<=[_[:alnum:]]\+\)\(.*):\)\@=
```

I tried to use functions like `matchlist`, `match`, `matchstr`, `matchend` with different configuration (trying some crazy stuffs with `match`, `matchstr` and `matchend` in a loop) but i didn't succeed.

Is there a way to get all the words matching a regular expression in a list in vimscript ?

I really want to keep this single regexp if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a substitution and use `\=` to gather up the matches.

```
:let lst = []
:%s/^\s*\zsdef\s\+.*):\ze\s*$/\=add(lst, submatch(0))/n
```

Note: this causes changes the search register.

Using the `n` flag as @Christian Brabandt suggests will prevent making changes to the buffer.

I also simplified your regex to search for lines starting with `def` and ending with `):`

For more information see:

```
:h :s
:h :s/\=
:h /\zs
:h :s_flags
```

Comment: Use the 'n' flag to the `:s` call to avoid changing the buffer (and creating unnecessary undo states)